# Getting different estimates of the mean with or without lapply, even when specifying na.rm = T in all cases

Tags: r, mean

I have spent several hours trying to trouble shoot this issue, albeit unsuccessfully.
I have over a hundred outcome variables I am trying to estimate their means. When computed individually (i.e., not in a loop or vectorized form), I get the correct estimate. Once I used lapply or some similar code, I get slightly different estimates.

Here are the stand-alone codes that gave the right answer:

```
 prop.table(table(x$polytobacco))
 mean(x$polytobacco, na.rm = T)
```

However, below is the apply statement that gave the wrong estimate:

```
varlist = c("polytobacco, ....") # over 100 variables
meanestimates = as.matrix(round(sapply(y[,varlist], function(x) mean(as.numeric(x), na.rm = T)), 1)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% t
```

Thanks in advance.

Ter.

Comment: It should be the same ideally. How much is the difference? Is it because you are rounding? Can you provide an example with small number of columns which gave wrong estimate?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, less is more. I simplified the code it now gives the correct results.

**#Overall**

```
  pooledov = lapply(x[,outcomes], function(x) mean(x, na.rm = T)) %>% as.data.frame()
  rownames(pooledov) = "Total"
  colnames(pooledov) = outcomes
```

**>  #analyses for subgroups**

```
means = foreach(o = outcomes) %:%
    foreach (p = predictors) %do% {
      tapply(x[,o], x[,p], mean, na.rm =T) %>% as.data.frame()
}
```